# Find first inversion for an element in an array

Tags: arrays, algorithm, sorting, merge, mergesort

Given an Array A with indices `1 <= i <= n`, find the very first j, `i + 1 <= j <= n`, such that `A[j] > A[i]`. To find the total number of inversions for any given element, we create a copy of A and mergesort that copy. Then for each i in A, we perform a binary search on the copy of A(call it B) to locate it's position and the number of inversion for that element is one less then it's position in the copy of A. I understand this, but i'm having trouble determining how to modify this approach to locate the minimum possible conversion.

Example: `A = {8, 3, 34, 13, 1, 2, 21, 5}`
After copy and merge: `B = {1, 2, 3, 5, 8, 13, 21, 34}`
               indices:   `{5, 6, 2, 8, 1, 4, 7, 3}`

We see A[1] = 8, do a binary search on Array B, we find 8 at position 5, the algorithm should return 34 (index 3). If no inversion exists, return -1.

Complexity should be O(nlogn), i've sat through this problem for a few hours and can't think of a solution, all I could think of is finding the number of inversion but not the index j. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this helpful http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/next-greater-element/ ?  I think it does what you want in O(n)

Comment: @PeterdeRivaz It's helpful, but I'm trying to learn how to do this with merge sort for an exam coming up. I don't need code, just a high level description of what should be done.

Comment: Your example makes no sense to me. Could you please explain more? Please note that the first inversion with 8 is  with the number 3 as 3 is after 8 and has smaller value. I don't understand at all why you say first inversion is with 34. Please give more detailed explanation showing how you fill the indices array

Comment: @IvayloStrandjev I'm sorry, I explained it wrong, what I meant was find the first biggest number after an index. So for example, the first biggest number after 8 is 34, after 3 is also 34, there is no bigger number after 34 so we return -1. After the number 1 the biggest number is 2, so we return 2. Like that.